# Mootools Image Sliding Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, mootools

Does anybody know a similar plugin to [Flow Slider](http://www.flowslider.com) but for Mootools?

Comment: Don't know, but Flow Slider is useless unless the author decides to publish the licensing terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin I made some time ago for myself. **[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/gc49Y/2/)**.

As you can see, it's quite identical to the jQuery plugin you linked.

You can find **[the Mootools plugin itself here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g43g2iWz)**, and then you just need *(as you can see in the fiddle)*:

```
var myPanner = new Panner('theItemsContainer', { limit: true, center: true });
```

It's ***important*** that you look at CSS rules in the demo I made for you, I commented the needed ones!!!

Let me know!!!

Comment: I've got **[a page on Forge](http://mootools.net/forge/profile/lorenzo.stanco)**, with four plugins. I did not add this too 'cause it's very raw and not much coder friendly. I will do it the day I will improve it for some reason.